# What happens to DNS requests when using a proxy?

Tags: ip

First question on this forum.
When I'm using a proxy in a browser (not on the whole system) what happens to DNS requests? What I mean is, are DNS requests going through the proxy as well, or are they being handled separately, thus exposing your my IP? Does it depend on how a proxy server is configured, or does all proxy servers handle DNS requests the same way?

I don't have any background in  IT, so I probably won't be able to understand too technical answers.

Thanks!